# Kafka console producer does not fail if broker address is incorrect

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I run the following command (where `<incorrect port>` is a number):

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:<incorrect port> --topic some-topic
```

And the process doesnt fail, it continues as if nothing is wrong

Is there a way upon startup of kafka-console-producer.sh  to check the destination broker port has a broker listening to that port upon startup?

I'm using kafka 0.10.2.0 on osx 10.12.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design... The producer just assumes, that the broker will get available at the specified port eventually. However, the producer should time out at some point (IIRC the default is 5 minutes). You can reduce the timeout config to get the error earlier via `request.timeout.ms` or `metadata.fetch.timeout.ms`.